# How to know which function was called

Tags: c#

I'm using a delegate to dynamically choose between many functions i.e

```
delegate bool CtrlTransfer(int xferLength, ref byte[] buffer);

bool CtrlRead(int xferLength, ref byte[] buffer)
{ /* do a read */ }

bool CtrlWrite(int xferLength, ref byte[] buffer)
{ /* do a write */ }
```

and these are used in a dispatching function as

```
byte[] RunTest(CtrlTransfer ctrlXferFunction, /* a bunch of other args */) {
    /* do some stuff */
    ctrlXferFunction(/* its arguments */);
    /* do some more stuff */
    return someByteArray;
}
```

The reason I'm using a delegate as opposed to some argument indicating the direction is that `ctrlXferFunction` is called many times and using `if {..} else {..}` everywhere becomes very tedious.

My problem now is that I don't know which control transfer function was actually called. If I try `if(ctrlXferFunction == CtrlRead)` a la Python or JavaScript, I get the error that `==` cannot be used between a method group and CtrlTransfer.

Is there a way to know which function was actually called?

(My apologies if I made any terminology mistakes. I'm new to C#)

Comment: What are you going to do with this info? Why not add the logic within the `CtrlRead` and `CtrlWrite` functions?

Comment: @KarthikT The CtrlRead and Write functions do just one thing -- a read or write on the control endpoint (USB). Eventually, the RunTest function will have to expand to incorporate other types of reads/writes also. And the interface to do transfers on different endpoints are different -- hence the different functions

Comment: I was actually asking about what you will do once you determine which function is being called

Comment: There's some data-specific cleanup and processing to be done between reads. This isn't included in the CtrlRead function due to the specificity.

Comment: Maye you can write a CtrlReadWithCleanup wrapper which calls CtrlRead with the cleanup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Method` property on the delegate:

```
if( ctrlXferFunction.Method.Name == "CtrlRead" ) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were in you, I'd use an interface rather a delegate. That will lead to an easier info retrieval about what's the caller.

```
interface IMyInterface
{
  bool CtrlTransfer(int xferLength, ref byte[] buffer);
}
```

Then:

```
class MyReader : IMyInterface
{
  bool CtrlTransfer(int xferLength, ref byte[] buffer)
  {
    // do the read...
  }
}
```

Finally:

```
var reader = ctrlXferInstance as MyReader;
if (reader != null)
{
  // ...
}
```